# Results of MYSQL query printed twice using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am a teacher and I have a mysql table called 'gabber' which holds scores of student quizzes.  The fields are 'Exercise', 'realname, 'Score', 'Start_Time' and 'End_Time'.  If a student completes more than one type of quiz, then this will appear as another row in the table, but of course with a different Exercise value.

My code below, which very nearly works, first finds the unique exercise values, and uses these to print the table column headings.  These unique exercise values are also used to create the second query, which finds the minimum (i.e. first attempt) score for each student's attempt at each quiz.

Anyway, the php code works EXCEPT for printing each value twice.  i.e. the name is printed twice, as is each score.  I know that my query is definitely correct (tested in phpmyadmin), but I think things are going wrong in the nested for loop.  I have tried reading about PDOstatement which the query returns, but I could not understand it.  I appreciate that there are other posts on stackoverflower about "printing twice", but they could not help me solve this.

Any suggestions on how to make this work would be excellent.  Thanks, Matt.

```
<?
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=XXX;dbname=gabber", user, pass);
$query2 = "SELECT realname";

echo '<style>table{border-collapse:collapse;}';
echo 'table, td, th{border:1px solid black;}</style>';
echo '<table><tr><td></td>';

foreach($dbh->query('SELECT DISTINCT Exercise FROM a2_physics') as $row) {
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row[0];
    echo '</td>';
    $query2.=', MIN( IF( Exercise = "';
    $query2.=$row[0];
    $query2.='", Score, NULL ) ) AS "';
    $query2.=$row[0];
    $query2.='"';
    }
echo '</tr>';

$query2=$query2.' FROM a2_physics';
$query2=$query2.' GROUP BY realname';

//echo $query2;
foreach($dbh->query($query2) as $row) {
echo '<tr>';
foreach($row as $element)
{
echo '<td>';
echo $element;
echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: this is pdo or this is new fetching method ?

Comment: have you heard about the .= operator?

Comment: I believe I am using PDO, and I have not used a fetch method.  But i'm afraid I am very new to sql

Comment: thanks Steven, I will implement that to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

When connecting to PDO, do it this way

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Will these options you have specified prevent my data printing twice?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  This collapsed the table down completely and only gave me the first column (names).

Comment: No, but it's a start to better coding practices. Now you can start using the fieldnames instead of field indexes. eg `$row['Excercise']` instead of `$row[0]`. That should help you better understand what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, one of these options exactly for this purpose

Comment: thanks Common Sense, but i'm afraid it only prints the names when I implement your suggestion, and no scores.

Comment: it seems it's your query. May be make it less entangled? or at least make it return consistent set of values?

Comment: I don't think it is the query.  Provided that the mysql table does not change then it does always produce a consistent set of values.  I tried echoing the final $query2 string, and using it in phpmyadmin, and it works.  I think things are going wrong in the nested for loop.  Or I do not know how to "extract" the data from the result of the query.

Comment: mr. common sense didn't really answer the question there. I've been having the same double-printing problem, and apparently it's because the attributes are, by default, stored twice. Here's how: if your table has columns a1 & a2, each $row is going to contain each column twice, one indexed by number and another indexed associatively. So your $row actually contains $row[0], $row["a1"], $row[1], $row["a2"]. The option that mr common sense wrote that broke your code is "PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC", making it so that you can no longer call $row[0], only $row["a1"].